# I can clone repo and pull, but I can't push

Tags: git, github, push

I'm trying to push changes to the remote repo, but for some reason I can't.

When I `git branch` this is what I see:

```
develop
feature/all_features
* feature/Tommaso
```

And when I `git status`:

```
On branch feature/Tommaso
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I could `clone` the repo and `pull` from the develop, but when I do `git pull` this is what I get:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.
git pull <remote> <branch>
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature/Tommaso
```

I guess the problem is that the remote repo does not have the current branch I created locally.

**EDIT:** I was not sufficiently clear: I'd like to create the branch `feature/Tommaso` in `feature/allfeatures` . I say this for those of you who may have thought I was trying to create a branch of the `develop`

Is that it? How can I solve it?

Tell me if you need other info to address the issue. Thank you in advance

Comment: first thing you look is that specify a branch from which you want to pull using `git pull origin branch_name` .This is the solution for your problenm

Comment: Thank you! Let me be sure about this: 

If I want feature/Tommaso to be a branch of feature/allfeatures is it sufficient to do this: git pull origin feature/allfeatures ? 

After this it asks me: Merge branch 'feature/allfeatures' of https://name_of_repository into feature/Tommaso, is this correct? 

Please answer and I accept your comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below commands.

```
$ git pull origin <branch_name>

$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/<branch_name>
```

If you want to create your own integration branch.

```
$ git checkout -b <integration branch name> origin/<origin branch name>

$ git push origin <integration branch name>
```

Comment: Thanks, I would accept everybody's answer since my issue was both in not having a Clear idea of local and remote tree, having no authorization to write and then the fact I needed ti create a branch in another branch. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 3):

> I guess the problem is that the remote repo does not have the current branch I created locally

I also think that's the problem. First, `push` your current branch with `-u` flag (set upstream), then try `git pull`.

```
$ git push -u origin HEAD
```

**N.B:**  `-u = --set-upstream` tells Git to remember the parameters, so that next time we can simply run `git pull` or `git push`.

When you run only `git pull` without mentioning branch name, git tries to pull from tracking remote branch.

```
$ git pull
```

if you want to pull another remote branch then just mention branch name.

```
$ git pull origin <branch-name>
```

---

If you want a new branch `feature/Tommaso` from `feature/allfeatures` then follow:

```
$ git checkout feature/allfeatures
$ git checkout -b feature/Tommaso
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Now, `feature/allfeatures` and `feature/Tommaso` have the same changes/commits.

Comment: Thank you for the answer: just to check, have you seen the edit? 

I guess with the edit the answer is: git pull origin feature/allfeatures and then git push -u origin feature/Tommaso?

Comment: "I'd like to create the branch feature/Tommaso in feature/allfeatures", not clear what you want exactly. Would you explain more?

Comment: I have the develop which is the master. From develop we have a branch called feature/allfeatures on which we are working and here I want to create a branch called feature/Tommaso

Comment: I would not suggest using / in branch names but you can do `git checkout -b feature-Tommaso`

Comment: If you want a new branch **feature/Tommaso** from **feature/allfeatures** then 
 follow: `git checkout feature/allfeatures`, `git checkout -b ffeature/Tommaso`. Now,   *feature/allfeatures* and *feature/Tommaso* have the same changes/commits.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with branches then you have to keep an identical branch with remote in order to be consistent. Suppose if you have a branch on remote repo named foo then you have to keep a branch name foo in the local also.

How do you do this. Assuming you don't have branch named foo in your local repo so you do

```
$ git fetch
```

It will get the information about all the branches in the remote to your local which can be clear from the output of this command.

Then you do a `git branch` to see what are the branches available. Now you will be able to see branch foo in your local. Do a `git checkout -b foo` this will switch your branch to foo. Use `git log` to see you have up-to-date branch with remote else do `git pull origin foo`. Now you can use `git push origin foo`.

The log mentioned in your comment suggest that you are trying to pull from a different branch and working with other branch in local repo. Switch branches before you start working otherwise you will run in merge conflicts and mess up the repo

Comment: Thanks: I have a clearer view of what happens under the hood. 
I'll review other answers thanks

Comment: glad to help. Take your time to understand before accepting any answer

Answer (score 2):

As other already said there is no branch named

Use this code

`git push origin <your branch name>`

Edited

have you already done it?

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/MyRepo/project.git`

Comment: ok can you check you authorizations? There may be a case that you have read access only.

Comment: I mean which repo you are using is it private? You got access from someone else? then just confirm once again that do you have write auth or not.

Comment: I have this in my repo .gitconfig
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/MyRepo/project.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master
And I can clone just fine but still can't push, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can encounter this if you have read but not write permission for the repo.